# $u ( x, y) = 2x (1− y)$ for all real $x$ and $y$

Tags: complex-analysis

I am stuck on the following problem :

> Let $u ( x, y) = 2x (1− y)$ for all real $x$ and $y$.
>   Then a function v ( x, y), so that
>   $f ( z) = u ( x, y) + iv (x, y)$ is analytic, is
>
> (a) $x^2-(y-1)^2$
>
> (b) $x^2+(y-1)^2$
>
> (c) $(x-1)^2-y^2$
>
> (d) $(x-1)^2+y^2$

My Attempt: For analytic function $f(z)$, it must satisfy the *Cauchy-Riemann* equation.
$u_x=v_y \implies v_y=2(1-y) \implies v=2y-y^2 +c$. Now,I am stuck. Can someone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: you have a slight mistake in your reasoning. The partial with respect to $v_{y} = 2(1-y) \implies v = 2y - y^{2} + h(x)$... using this, which of the answers makes sense?

Comment: Thanks a lot. Then ,option 1 is the correct choice.Am I right?

Comment: That's right. Take $h(x) = -1 + x^{2}$. Then we have $v = x^{2} - y^{2} + 2y - 1 = x^{2} - (y-1)^{2}$. Notice it can't be any of the other answers because of an incorrect sign (as in (b)) or because of missing $y$ terms (as in (c) and (d))

Comment: My pleasure! Glad I could help.